# Prevent bootstrap modal closing on postback in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal I want to show in order to perform a search and select funcionality in a ASP.NET Web form. The problem is when the user clicks on "Search" button, the modal closes. I want the modal keeps open to show search results on GridView below and closes when the user selects any GridView item.

I've tried other solutions mentioned in other threads but nothing seems to work. I'm using a WebForm with a Master page, I don't know if it can be causin me the issue.

This is my modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modSearchByAccount" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Search by Account</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchText" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Account name"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                     <asp:Button ID="btnSearchAccount" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearchAccount_Click" Text="Buscar" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                     <asp:Panel ID="pnlSearchResults" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="200px" Width="100%">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvSearchResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ACCOUNT_ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ACCOUNT_ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ACCOUNT_NAME" HeaderText="Name" />
                                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton ="true" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
 </div>
```

Any ideas? Can I use an UpdatePanel somewhere here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the button is causing a post-back then the modal isn't closing, the *page is reloading*.  You'd need to trigger the modal to re-open when the page loads.  Or perhaps perform the operation via AJAX instead of reloading the page in the first place.

Comment: I tried to re-open the modal, but it doesn't looks nice, it hides and a second lather it's shown. Can I use an UpdatePanel inside the modal and around the buttons?

Comment: Can you use ajax to do the post instead of a full post?  That way you could prevent the default action of the post (so there is no reload), and just update your form based on what is returned. Then make sure there is no dismiss property on your button that posts the data.

Comment: Look here: https://sandywebdesigner.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/using-c-code-to-force-bootstrap-modal-stay-open-after-page-postback/

Comment: That's excatly what I did @Icemanind, but as I said it doesn't look nice, disappearing and then appearing.

Comment: @GustavoAlvarado - There is no way to prevent that. Because of the fact you're doing a "Post Back", then by definition, the page must post back, then reload the content again. If you need to avoid this, my suggestion would be to implement a service layer and then do an AJAX call to your service layer instead of a post back. Doing an AJAX call prevents post backs and thus prevents the reloading of your page, thus preventing closing of your modal.

Answer (score 8):

Probably too late now, but yes it can be done. The key is to have an outer UpdatePanel and an inner UpdatePanel. The outer panel should be set to an UpdateMode of conditional and ChildrenAsTriggers = true.

In my case I moved the inner body into a User Control, but your code example should work as follows:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanelTop" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modSearchByAccount" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Search by Account</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchText" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Account name"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                             <asp:Button ID="btnSearchAccount" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearchAccount_Click" Text="Buscar" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                             <asp:Panel ID="pnlSearchResults" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="200px" Width="100%">
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvSearchResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ACCOUNT_ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ACCOUNT_ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ACCOUNT_NAME" HeaderText="Name" />
                                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton ="true" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div> 
     </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Wow, what a simple solution for something I thought was going to be cumbersome and tedious to work around.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: Worked for me. Funny thing that inside of function tjat I called on postback I was unable to get values from conrolls if they are inside of try-catch block...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the UpdatePanel with Select2List or Some other bootstrap like FileUpload Controls, they will not properly render on **Auto Post Back**

To avoid this don't use the Update Panel just add the following code in code behind. This code will keep your Bootstrap Popup open after AutoPostBack Event.

```html
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "$('#MyPopup').modal('show')", true);
}
```

Comment: Well hot dang, the last answer at the bottom of the page was the simplest answer, and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I came upon this thread with the same problem.  The other solutions did not work for me, but I came up with my own that seems to work, although it might be considered a "hack".  Basically, in the code-behind I set up the various attributes of HTML elements the same way that Bootstrap does it.  I figured out what to set them to by comparing the Page Source when the dialog was "closed" vs. when "open".

Here's the top of the markup for my modal:

```
                        <div id="modalSizeChange" runat="server" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCloseMatItem" class="close" runat="server" Text='&times;' OnClick="btnCloseMatItem_Click" OnClientClick="$('#modalSizeChange').modal('hide')" />
                            <h2 id="ResizeDlgHdr" runat="server">Change Size of Return Piece</h2>
                        </div>
```

And here are two subroutines (this is vb.net) for keeping the modal open or closing it:

```
    Private Sub HideResizeDlg()
    modalSizeChange.Style.Remove("display")
    modalSizeChange.Attributes("class") = "modal hide fade"
    modalSizeChange.Attributes("aria-hidden") = "true"
    litDlgBackdrop.Text = ""
    litDlgBackdrop.Visible = False

    'Following is to remove any Div with "modal-backdrop fade in" class created by JQuery (instead of the one created by code-behind)
    Dim script As String = "$('.modal-backdrop').remove();"
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "#modalBackdropRemove", script, True)
End Sub

Private Sub ShowResizeDlg()
    'Set the attributes of the dialog so it stays visible on the post back - this matches the state after the JQuery .modal('show') is called
    modalSizeChange.Style.Add("display", "block")
    modalSizeChange.Attributes("class") = "modal hide fade in"
    modalSizeChange.Attributes("aria-hidden") = "false"
    litDlgBackdrop.Text = "<div class=""modal-backdrop fade in""></div>"
    litDlgBackdrop.Visible = True

End Sub
```

So whenever during postback I want to keep the dialog displayed, I call ShowResizeDlg().
The one problem with this approach is that after reloading the page, the close/cancel buttons no longer work using basic client-side .modal('hide') call, for the same reasons that the dialog didn't stay open.  So to get around that I made those post-back buttons as well, and they call the HideResizeDlg() subroutine which does the equivalent of 'hide'.

A note about litDlgBackdrop, which is a literal at the bottom just before the `</body>` tag.  I found out that the version of bootstrap used in my app achieves the darkened background effect by adding a `<div>` at this location with the class="modal-backdrop fade in".  So to achieve the same affect I populate this literal with the same thing.

In the HideResizeDlg(), I register a startup script that looks for and deletes any elements with class "modal-backdrop" - to get rid of the one created by bootstrap.

One other caution, the app I'm working on is using an old Bootstrap version from 2013, so the attributes I'm setting may not work with newer versions, but you could take a similar approach by studying the Page Source like I did to find out what to change.

There's probably a much better way, I just found this works for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Modal outside the updatepanel, if the modal inside the updatepanel the modal will close automatically when postback or asp button clicked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).